# Toggling display of multiple related elements

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have two sets of buttons for every package, one for inserting data into my database and the other for deleting data from the database.

When I click the 'Select' button data will be inserted through AJAX and then hide the 'Select' button and display the 'Selected' button. When I click on the 'Selected' button the data will be deleted from the database through an AJAX call. The 'Selected' button will then be hidden and the 'Select' button will be shown again.

All the select & selected buttons are within a PHP `while` loop so the buttons have the same name but incremental IDs. When I click on one single 'Select' button, the other button is also showing me 'Selected'. I need something to track the each button ID when I click.

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
  <a class="btn btn-primary select-btn select-btn-broadcast" id="<?php echo $id ; ?>" onClick="addintoListBroadcast(this)">Select</a>
  <a class="btn btn-primary active-button active-button-broadcast" id="<?php echo $id ; ?>" onClick="deleteintoListBroadcast(this)" style="display: none;">Selected</a>
</div>

<script>
  $('.select-btn-broadcast').click(function (e) {
    var pkgId = this.id;
    //alert(pkgId);
    $('.select-btn-broadcast').hide();
    $('.active-button-broadcast').show();
  });

  $('.active-button-broadcast').click(function(e) {
    $('.select-btn-broadcast'.show();
    $('.active-button-broadcast').hide();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Where's the rest of your code? There is only one button given in your code. Additionally, please don't use irrelevant tags, as PHP is not involved here after all

Comment: From a usability perspective, you should not be using an `a` here to begin with, but an actual `button`. And your actual problem can be fixed, if inside your handler functions, you first of all go up to the parent element of the currently clicked button (`.parent()`, or `.parents()` if operating at a deeper nesting level), and then select the element with the other class only in the context of that parent (`.find()`).

Answer (score 1):

The main issue with your code is because you select *all* the elements with the given class, not just the one related to the element which was clicked. To fix this use the `this` keyword to traverse the DOM to find the `sibling()` `a` element, and then amend it as required.

Also note that there's several other things you can improve in your code. Firstly, don't use inline CSS. Use the classes you've already applied to the elements to amend their styling in an external stylesheet.

Similarly, don't use inline event handlers such as `onclick`. Call the relevant functions within the unobtrusive event handlers you've bound through jQuery.

With all that said, here's a working example:

```js
$('.select-btn-broadcast').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).hide().siblings('.active-button-broadcast').show();
  // addintoListBroadcast(this);
});

$('.active-button-broadcast').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).hide().siblings('.select-btn-broadcast').show();
  // deleteintoListBroadcast(this);
});
```

```css
.active-button-broadcast {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-2">
  <a class="btn btn-primary select-btn select-btn-broadcast">Select</a>
  <a class="btn btn-primary active-button active-button-broadcast">Selected</a>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
  <a class="btn btn-primary select-btn select-btn-broadcast">Select</a>
  <a class="btn btn-primary active-button active-button-broadcast">Selected</a>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
  <a class="btn btn-primary select-btn select-btn-broadcast">Select</a>
  <a class="btn btn-primary active-button active-button-broadcast">Selected</a>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped